# Android twitter oAuth: failed to validate oauth signature and token

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

I try to auth in twitter using webview, and my code is such:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new TwitterWebViewClient());
String postData = "oauth_consumer_key=eT*9ax***1HT5TnI6**8**vE&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%3A3005%2Ftwitter%2Fprocess_callback";
mWebView.postUrl("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "HMAC-SHA1"));
```

but in result i see:

```
failed to validate oauth signature and token
```

what i do wrong?

i didn't want to use any third party libs, only hardcode :)

how to get token, so that i could go next and authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you want to do it the hard way, but Twitter just launched an official SDK that with only a few lines of code you have Sign in with Twitter working and with all alternate authentication flows implemented (having Twitter app installed, not installed, user cancelation, etc)

Check: http://t.co/fabric

Example:

```
private void setUpTwitterButton() {
    twitterButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_button);
    twitterButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            // TODO: success flow
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // TODO: failure flow
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to see a app sample with this SDK: https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android

Comment: and what if author didn't want to use default twitter app, on devise  ?

Comment: what lib's also could you provide? Also my app didn't must be "connected" to default twitter app... device could be without default app

Comment: If the Twitter app is not available it will fallback to a Webview app authorization, just like the one you have in Browsers.

Comment: brabertaser1992, sorry, didn't understand your question, can you explain?

Comment: what also lib's could i use, without fabric  ?

Comment: sorry, didn't understand your question, can you explain? –  what do you mean?

Comment: also - sometimes sdk work's really slow, btw fabric - didn't want to sign up me

Comment: brabertaser1992, the alternative to Fabric would be to implement the OAuth flow by yourself, using Twitter4j. Fabric team is working to get users access as fast as possible.